# Ruby Console Help with a One-to-Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Hello I've set up a One-to-Many Association between "orders" and "users". I'm wondering how to have console just return an array containing ID's rather than a full array of data:

> > user = User.find_by_login("Lesa")
> >
> > user.orders
> >     => [#, #]
> >
> > user.orders.id

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<User:0x10351f320>
    from /Users/justinz/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):10
```

I also tried user.order.id, and received the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the ID from each item using map:

```
user.orders.map(&:id)
```

Comment: I whish Ruby 2.0 would deprecate either map or collect... How about collect just because it has more characters?

Comment: @jonas, neither name is all that great really, but at least "map" is familiar from other languages like Haskell and PHP. I'm not aware of "collect" being used anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethod
**"singular_collection_ids"**

```
user.order_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symbol `to_proc` shortcut provided by Rails

```
user.orders.collect(&:id)
```

This is shorthand for

```
user.orders.collect { |o| o.id }
```

Comment: I whish Ruby 1.9 would deprecate either map or collect... How about collect just because it has more characters?